# Commentator badge awarded twice in a Stack Overflow Team

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, stack-overflow-for-teams

I belong to a Stack Overflow Team. Somehow, I was awarded the Commentator badge twice.

> [image]

I thought I wasn't that talkative... :)

Checking the [list of users who got that badge](https://stackoverflow.com/c/moderators/help/badges/31) I found [another case](https://stackoverflow.com/c/moderators/users/223/), getting it also on Jun 1 at 4:10 and 4:19.

Comment: Will attempt to reproduce in ~352 days, around 4:10 p.m.

Comment: I can't seem to find the issue here. Could you draw a red free-hand circle to point it out?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has been fixed and is currently live.

The cause of this issue was due to how we schedule/batch badge grants. We run the grant process every 5 minutes, but due to the sheer number of teams that we have, the process was not finishing before the next scheduled grant ran. This was causing the newly scheduled process to potentially re-grant the badge if the first process hadn’t yet finished.

The short term fix was to change the scheduler to grant badges once every hour and to add a unique db constraint to not allow badges to be granted for the same reason twice. In addition, we’ve removed all the duplicated badges.

We are currently investigating a more scalable long-term fix.

Thank your for your report.

Comment: Thanks! I thought my duplicate badge would be removed, now I have extra metal to sell :)